# How to add a 0 in front of number in C for formatting?

Tags: c, format, printf, long-integer

I have the value of `seconds` as simple number like `0`, or `60`, and I want to print it in the format of `00:00:00`. So for example, 60 seconds would display like `00:01:00`.

So I have a values:

```
unsigned long long sec; 
unsigned long long min;
unsigned long long hr; 
unsigned long long t;
```

and I do this:

```
//pass in value of seconds 
hr = sec/3600;
t = sec%3600; 
min= t/60;
sec = t%60;

char *colon = ":";

printf("%llu%s%llu%s%llu\t", hr,colon,min,colon,sec);
```

This would print partially what I want, something like `0:1:0`, from the previous example. However, I need an extra 0 in front if it's just 1 character length.... the only way I could think of doing this was to convert to a string and concatinate a zero at the beginning if the length is 1, but I feel like there's a better way.... I just don't know it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a numerical field width before each `%u` specifier to give it a particular size.  In this case, that would be `2`.

You then add the `0` flag before that to indicate that the field should be left-padded with zeros.

```
printf("%02llu%s%02llu%s%02llu\t", hours,colon,minutes,colon,seconds);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! :) So basically, the field should be of length 2, and if not pad it at the beginning with 0's until it gets to 2.

Comment: That words great another option could be %02d